# How do I go to the previous active cell?

Tags: excel, vba

Problem:  If a change is made to a cell I need to record who made the change to that Cell. Therefore, first i need to find the row number where change took place.
In general when data is typed most often "Enter" button is used in Excel, in this case I can offset by one row to get actual row number:
**RowNo = ActiveCell.Row -1** ' Works for Enter button or Down Arrow Key.

However, if the user **decides to use the mouse keys instead** and move **Left/Right/up** then my positioning is incorrect.

Below is my updated code, which fails on Activecell.Previous

Please help.

Code is on the Sheet itself to invoke upon cell change:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

*Dim KeyCells1 As Range
Dim PreviousCell As Integer
Set KeyCells1 = Range("A:B")
If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells1, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then

        PreviousCell = ActiveCell.Previous.Row
End If
End Sub*
```

All I need is the row number where change took place.
your help & suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: The changed cell is `Target`.

Answer (score 0):

If only one cell is being modified:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells1 As Range
    Dim PreviousCell As Integer

    Set KeyCells1 = Range("A:B")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells1, Target) Is Nothing Then
        PreviousCell = Target.Row
    End If
End Sub
```